# ИКМ по A-закону. Сильный шум

Tags: c#, .net

Попытался реализовать ИКМ по А-закону. Функцию преобразования взял из вики. Но в итоге получается слишком большой шум. Подозреваю, что это из-за неправильных преобразований (BitArray -> short, short -> byte и т.п.), но их я проверял несколько раз. Подскажите, что я сделал не так.
Функция кодирования:

```
    private static byte Encode(bool[] word)
    {
        var bits = new BitArray(word);
        var number = bits.ToInt16();
        var x = number / (float)Max;
        var absX = Abs(x);
        float y;

        if (0 <= absX && absX < (1 / A))
        {
            y = (float) (Sign(x)*(A*absX/(1 + Log(A))));
        }
        else
        {
            y = (float) (Sign(x)*((1 + Log(A*absX))/(1 + Log(A))));
        }

        y *= byte.MaxValue;
        return (byte) y;
    }
```

Функция декодирования:

```
    private static short Decode(bool[] code)
    {
        var bits = new BitArray(code);
        var number = bits.ToByte();
        var y = number / (float)Max;
        var absY = Abs(y);

        float x;

        if (absY < 1 / (1 + Log(A)))
        {
            x = (float) (Sign(y)*(absY*(1 + Log(A))/A));
        }
        else
        {
            x = (float) (Sign(y)*(Exp(absY*(1 + Log(A)) - 1)/A));
        }

        x *= short.MaxValue;
        return (short)x;
    }
```

На вход функциям подаётся битовые представления чисел short и byte соответственно.

Comment: Если вы уточните, что такое ИКМ, ваш вопрос будет полезен гораздо большему кругу людей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в использовании беззнакового типа `byte`. Решение: использовать `sbyte`.